# How can this SQL check constraint for time ranges fail, when table is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, check-constraints

I have implemented a time range validation, as a check constraint, using a function in SQL, using [this guide](https://sqlspellbook.com/2015/02/12/2/), almost to the letter.

Creating the function first:

```
create function dbo.ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange
(
    @btf_id VARCHAR(32),
    @start_time BIGINT,
    @end_time BIGINT
)
returns bit
as
begin
declare @Valid bit = 1;

if exists( select *
           from   dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence o
           where  o.btf_id = @btf_id
           and    @start_time <= o.end_time and o.start_time <= @end_time )
   set @Valid = 0;
return @Valid;
```

end

And then the constraint, using the function:

```
alter table dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence with nocheck add constraint 

CK_StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence_ValidateTimeRange 
    check (dbo.ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange(btf_id, start_time, end_time) = 1);
```

When I try to insert an element into a completely empty table, I get:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint 
"CK_StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence_ValidateTimeRange". The conflict occurred in 
database "D600600TD01_BSM_Surveillance", table "dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence".
```

I tried to figure out if I did something wrong in the function itself, and created this query to check it's return value:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
EXEC @ReturnValue =  ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange
@btf_id = 'a596933eff9143bceda5fc5d269827cd',
@start_time = 2432432,
@end_time = 432432423
SELECT @ReturnValue
```

But this returns 1, as it should.

I am at a loss on how to continue debugging this. All parts seem to work, but the whole does not. Any ideas on how the insert statement can conflict with the check constraint?

**Edit:** Here is my insert statement for completion:

```
INSERT INTO StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence (btf_id, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('a596933eff9143bceda5fc5d269827cd',2432432,432432423);
```

There is an additional primary key comlumn with identity auto increment.

Comment: The `CHECK` constraint fails because the row you inserted trips the very condition it's supposed to check -- the check logically happens after the insert has been done (but before it's rolled back). I think the author meant to write `where  o.btf_id <> @btf_id` rather than `where  o.btf_id = @btf_id`, to avoid just this occasion. (This assumes `btf_id` is itself a key, so no duplicates can be inserted.)

Comment: I have similair problem. I created new table with this constraint only. Now i can't insert any rows as check always fails...

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've read the article, good exercise combined with your comment. But the equality of ID's is crucial in this case. The point of such check is to avoid overlapping time periods for one id.

Comment: yeah, the btf_id is not the primary key for this table, but a foreign key reference. So it is definitevly needed.

Comment: I have no triggers

Comment: In that case you will have to add a surrogate key (like an identity) that allows you to distinguish between rows, otherwise this approach is doomed. Outside of a trigger, there is no way to distinguish the newly added row from an existing one.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, if the check happens after the insert as default, do you know of any way to change the order of execution? Otherwise this whole way of doing it seems impossible to me at least. Would be a shame, as I really really liked the idea of these kinds of check constraints.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I'll try to implement a SCOPE_IDENTITY() inside the function. That should get the last inserted ID, and hopefully disregard that single occurrence.

Comment: Don't do that! `CHECK` constraints must be valid in every context, and adding `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will break it something fierce if a row is updated. Explicitly pass the identity of the row to the function.

Comment: How can I do that when the ID is a auto incremented int?

Comment: Remember: the `CHECK` happens after the row is logically inserted, so the value is already known. You can simply defined the constraint as `check (dbo.ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange(id, btf_id, start_time, end_time) = 1)` and use `@id` and `id` in the function.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you are a genius :) It works like a charm now! If you'd write that up as an answer, I'll accept it right away. Thank you for both your skills and patience :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHECK` constraints happen after the row is inserted, so in its current form, the constraint fails because the very row that was inserted matches the constraint. In order for this to work as a constraint (not a trigger) there must be a way to distinguish the row we're checking from all other rows. [Michał's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49491111/4137916) shows how to do this without relying on an `IDENTITY`, but if you do have that explicitly excluding the row may be simpler:

```
create function dbo.ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange
(
    @id INT,
    @btf_id VARCHAR(32),
    @start_time BIGINT,
    @end_time BIGINT
)
returns bit
as
begin
declare @Valid bit = 1;

if exists( select *
           from   dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence o
           where  o.id <> @id AND o.btf_id = @btf_id
           and    @start_time <= o.end_time and o.start_time <= @end_time )
   set @Valid = 0;
return @Valid;
end;
```

with the constraint defined as

```
check (dbo.ValidateStatusPeriodInfoTimeRange(id, btf_id, start_time, end_time) = 1)
```

Regardless of the approach, indexes on `(btf_id, start_time)` and `(btf_id, end_time)` are a good idea to keep this scalable, otherwise a full table scan is necessary on every insert.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in comments, constraint is checked **after** the record is inserted into a table, then the transaction is commited or rolled back, depending on result of a check, which in your example will always fails, as query:

```
select *
from   dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence o
where  o.btf_id = @btf_id
and    @start_time <= o.end_time and o.start_time <= @end_time
```

will return always at least one row (the one being inserted).

So, knowing that, you should check if the query returns **more than one record**, so the condition in `if` statement should become:

```
if (select count(*)
          from   dbo.StatusPeriodInfoOccurrence o
          where  o.btf_id = @btf_id
          and    @start_time <= o.end_time and o.start_time <= @end_time ) > 1
```

This solution works fine (tested on my DB).

Comment: Very clever solution. I believe this would work every time, although I think the Jeroen way, with checking explicit for the id is a little bit cleaner and easy to read :)

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be much cleaner. Also requires adding extra column to your tables, thus altering function.

Comment: Yeah, you got a point. I already had the column though. Not cleaner then, but easier to read. At least for me. And it was the first solution provided, although in the comments.

Comment: This has the benefit of working even without an `IDENTITY` column. I'll write up an answer anyway, because the performance characteristics of the approaches may be different even if the range fields are both indexed (although in practice, I don't expect this).

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as accepted, but I have to go with the one who solved the problem first. Both are great though